# passing global variable to plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to pass a global variable into a plugin. The global variable is content loaded from a separate page

**This is my current code:**

```
$( "#results" ).load( "/content.html");
var rawevents = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;
```

I can log the *rawevents* variable in the console no dramas and the plain text comes back all fine

My problem is I need to get the plain text from this variable and shove it into the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events: [{

            RESULTS HERE,

            title: 'Holder',
            start: "2015-12-12",
            allDay: true,
            }],
    });
</script>
```

If possible, it would also be awesome if it could strip all white spaces/minify the code when it passes it through - I'm not going to get cocky about it though!

**Any help would be really, really appreciated. Cheers :)**
- Beau

Comment: from i can tell from the docs it's impossible to add raw data,how does `rawevents`  look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly, but I'll give it a shot.. if `rawevents` is a global variable and it exists and is populated before you're trying to use the plugin, you should just be able to use the variable in the plugin.

Unless I'm just misunderstanding your question.

Even if `rawevents` is a local variable declared in the same scope as where you're initializing that calendar, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

- Pass the data to plugin like this

  ```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      plainText:rawEvents
  });
  ```
- Then Retrieve the same in the plugin  as

  ```
  //Jquery Plugin extension
  jQuery.fn['fullCalendar'] = function (options){ return calendarFunc($(this),options);};

  //private function        
  var calendarFunc= function ($container,options){
       //process and Render calendar 
  }
  ```

  [For More Info on Jquery Plugin Creation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: i don't see any property called `plainText` in the docs can you provide a link to it?

Comment: Its passed as a object, which is received in`options` parameter inside `calendarFunc`. anyway you can access it like this `options.plainText`